# What's the C# method/syntax for converting an array to a simple string?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, join

What I'm looking for is a basic equivalent of JavaScript's `Array::join()` whereby you pass in a separator character and uses that in its return string of all the subscripts.  I could certainly write my own function using a `StringBuilder` or whatnot, but there *must* be something built into the .NET BCL.

EDIT: Array of *anything*, not necessarily `string` or `char`.  I'd prefer the method to simply call `ToString()` on each subscript `object`.  `String.Join()` is great except that you pass it an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array contains strings, you can just use [`String.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).  If the array does not contain strings, you'll need something a little more complicated so you can handle the cast or conversion process for each item it contains.

**Update:** Using @JaredPar's code as the basis for a more generic example:

```
char sep = GetSeparatorChar();
object[] toJoin = GetToJoin();
string joined = toJoin.Aggregate((x,y) => x.ToString()+sep.ToString()+y.ToString());
```

Obviously you could do anything you wanted to x and y in that example to get the string to look how you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If String.Join doesn't do it for you - e.g. you have an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string[]` or you have a collection of some other type, see [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/how-to-join-int-to-a-charcter-separated-string-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to whether or not you are joining an array of characters or strings.

For Strings

```
char sep = GetSeparatorChar();
string[] toJoin = GetToJoin();
string joined = toJoin.Aggregate((x,y) => x+sep.ToString()+y);
```