# F# on mono in leopard. Seq.cast error

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I came across this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332871/f-xml-parsing), but I can't seem to compile the code.  I'm getting the following error on Seq.cast:

error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'cast' is not defined.

I'm using Mono 2.0.1_1 and F# 1.9.4.19 on leopard.  Is there something funky with f# when running under mono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to the latest version of F# 1.9.6.2 (also known as the September CTP): 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=61ad6924-93ad-48dc-8c67-60f7e7803d3c&displaylang=en

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rob.  That was it.  I was able to get around it using map_to_typed in 1.9.4.19.

Seq.map_to_typed (fun e -> e :> System.Xml.XmlNode)