# Shortest method to convert an array to a string in c#/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

Closed as exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856).

I have an array/list of elements. I want to convert it to a string, separated by a custom delimitator. For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] => "1,2,3,4,5"
```

What's the shortest/esiest way to do this in c#?

I have always done this by cycling the list and checking if the current element is not the last one before adding the separator.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; ++i)
{
    str += arr[i].ToString();
    if(i<arr.Length)
        str += ",";
}
```

Is there a LINQ function that can help me write less code?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
String.Join(",", arr.Select(p=>p.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: You don't actually need the ToArray()... string.Join can take an IEnumerable, and IEnumerable.Select returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: @neminem `string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` did not exist in 2008.

Answer (score 39):

```
String.Join(",", array.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
```