# Cannot convert Array to String

Tags: c#, arrays, webmethod

I am using the following WebMethod-

```
[WebMethod]
    public string get_IDs(string uid)
    {


        string url = "www.foobar.com/id=-1&user_id=" + uid";

        String data = SearchData(url);

        JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

        string ids = (string)o["ids"];


        return ids;
    }
```

My problem being the data returned is in array form, I want it back as a string however this throws up the exception that cannont convert array to string. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - is `SearchData` returning an `Array` and not a `String`?  Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: How is Ids(plural) going to be returned as a single string?

Comment: @David Hoerster yes SearchData is bringing back a JSON withihn that JSONI am trying to get ids which are in an array. I am trying to return this as a string however cannot convert it to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted it -

```
string followers = (string)o["ids"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do `o["ids"].ToString();`  ??

I am unfamiliar with the JObject class, so if that does not have a ToArray function and if you are expecting more than 1 ID via JObject o variable you could try:

```
public List<string> get_IDs(string uid)
{


    string url = "www.foobar.com/id=-1&user_id=" + uid";

    String data = SearchData(url);

    JObject o = JObject.Parse(data);

    List<string> ids = new List<string>();

    foreach (obj in o) {
       ids.add(obj.ToString());
    } 
    return ids;

}
```

Notice the method type has from `string` to `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string result = string.Join(";", array);
return result;
```

What is the type of `o["ids"]`?

```
var ids = (string)o["ids"];
console.WriteLine(ids.GetType());
```

If `ids` is of type `int[]` you have to cast all elements to `String`. See: [C# Cast Entire Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array)

```
var strIds = Array.ConvertAll(ids, item => (String)item);
string result = string.Join(";", strIds);
return result;
```

If `ids` is an `JObject` you can use the ffollowing function of `JObject`:

```
public override IEnumerable<T> Values<T>()

IEnumerable<String> strIds = ids.Values<String>();
```

And Convert the Enumerable into a single `String` if needed: [C# IEnumerable<Object> to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372349/c-sharp-ienumerableobject-to-string)