# How to query in LINQ & Entity Framework the unmapped property

Tags: entity-framework, linq

So I partially followed from an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220921/how-to-store-double-array-to-database-with-entity-framework-code-first-approac/15221028#15221028) on how to store a property with array datatype in Entity Framework. What I didn't follow on that answer is setting the string InternalData to be private instead of public as I find it a code smell if it is set to public (not enough reputation to comment there yet).

I also managed to map the private property in entity framework from this [blog](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/26/code-first-data-annotations-on-non-public-properties/).

When I perform CR (create, read) from that entity, all goes well. However, when my LINQ query has a where clause using that property with array datatype, it says that *"System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'"*.

How to work around on this? Here are the relevant code blocks:

```
public class ReminderSettings
{
   [Key]
   public string UserID { get; set; }
   [Column("RemindForPaymentStatus")]
   private string _remindForPaymentStatusCSV { get; set; }
   private Status[] _remindForPaymentStatus;
   [NotMapped]
   public Status[] RemindForPaymentStatus
   {
      get 
      {
         return Array.ConvertAll(_remindForPaymentStatusCSV.Split(','), e => (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), e));
      }
      set
      {
         _remindForPaymentStatus = value;
         _remindForPaymentStatusCSV = String.Join(",", _remindForPaymentStatus.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
      }
   }
   public static readonly Expression<Func<ReminderSettings, string>> RemindForPaymentStatusExpression = p => p._remindForPaymentStatusCSV;
}

public enum Status
{
  NotPaid = 0,
  PartiallyPaid = 1,
  FullyPaid = 2,
  Overpaid = 3 
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<ReminderSettings>().Property(ReminderSettings.RemindForPaymentStatusExpression);
}

//This query will cause the error
public IEnumerable<ReminderSettings> GetReminderSettingsByPaymentStatus(Status[] statusArray)
{
   var query = ApplicationDbContext.ReminderSettings.Where(x => x.RemindForPaymentStatus.Intersect(statusArray).Any());
   return query.ToList(); //System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'RemindForPaymentStatus' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework can not translate LINQ expressions to SQL if they access a property that is annotated as `[NotMapped]`. (It also can not translate if the property contains custom C# code in its getter/setter).

As a quick (but potentially low performance) workaround, you can execute the part of the query that does not cause problems, then apply additional filtering in-memory.

```
// execute query on DB server and fetch items into memory
var reminders = dbContext.ReminderSettings.ToList(); 

// now that we work in-memory, LINQ does not need to translate our custom code to SQL anymore
var filtered = reminders.Where(r => r.RemindForPaymentStatus.Contains(Status.NotPaid));
```

If this causes performance problems, you have to make the backing field of your `NotMapped` property public and work directly with it.

```
var filtered = dbContext.ReminderSettings
    .Where(r => r._remindForPaymentStatusCSV.Contains(Status.NotPaid.ToString("D"));
```

**Edit** 
To handle multiple Status as query parameters, you can attach `Where` clauses in a loop (which behaves like an AND). This works as long as your Status enum values are distinguishable (i.e. there is no Status "11" if there is also a Status "1").

```
var query = dbContext.ReminderSettings.Select(r => r);
foreach(var statusParam in queryParams.Status) {
    var statusString = statusParam.ToString("D");
    query = query.Where(r => r._remindForPaymentStatusCSV.Contains(statusString));
}
var result = query.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Georg. I opt to choose the latter since it is scalable. Though in the where clause, I want to compare an array of status vs the parameter/inputted array of status. I edited my question for this matter. I tried composing a where clause with this one: but I still get an error.

var query = ApplicationDbContext.ReminderSettings
                .Where(x => Array.ConvertAll(x._remindForPaymentStatusCSV.Split(','), e => (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), e)).Intersect(statusArray).Any());
            return query.ToList();

Comment: You can also do this _without_ first materializing the data-set, provided your data is a good format (not CSV, but JSON would be far better): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953313/4564272