# It is possible to query a NotMapped property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

i'm working with EF6 code first, and i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207034/5213794) answer to map a `List<stirng>` in my entitie.

This is my class

```
    [Key]
    public string SubRubro { get; set; } 
    [Column]        
    private string SubrubrosAbarcados
    {
        get
        {
            return ListaEspecifica == null || !ListaEspecifica.Any() ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListaEspecifica);
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                ListaEspecifica.Clear();
            else
                ListaEspecifica = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(value);                
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> ListaEspecifica { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

It works perfectly to storage my list as Json, but now i need to perform a linq query, and i'm trying this

```
var c = db.CategoriaAccesorios.Where(c => c.ListaEspecifica.Contains("Buc")).First();
```

And it's throwing

> **System.NotSupportedException**: The specified type member
>   'ListaEspecifica' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only
>   initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

what is logical.

Is there any way to perform a query like this?

Comment: @KennethK. that was what i'm thinking, do you know a better solution to persist a `List` of primitive type?

Comment: _"The NotMapped attribute can be applied to properties of an entity class **for which we do not want to create corresponding columns in the database**"_ - so no, you can't query it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that LINQ to Entities does not understand how to convert your query to the back-end (SQL) language. Because you're not materializing (i.e. converting to .NET) the results of the query *until* you filter it, LINQ tries to convert your query to SQL itself. Since it's not sure how to do that, you get a `NotSupportedException`.

*If* you materialize the query first (I.e. call a `.ToList()`) then filter, things will work fine. I suspect this isn't what you want, though. (I.e. `db.CategoriaAccesorios.ToList().Where(c => c.ListaEspecifica.Contains("Buc")).First();`)

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919709/only-initializers-entity-members-and-entity-navigation-properties-are-supporte?) explains, your issue is the EF to SQL Conversion. Obviously you want some way to workaround it, though.

Because you are JSON serializing, there are actually a couple options here, most particularly using a [`LIKE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913697/how-to-do-a-like-query-with-linq):

```
var c =
    (from category
     in db.CategoriaAccessorios
     where SqlMethods.Like(c.SubrubrosAbarcados, "%\"Buc\"%")
     select category).First()
```

If EF Core, allegedly `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF.Functions.Like` should replace `SqlMethods.Like`.

If you have SQL Server 2016+, and force the `SubrubrosAbarcados` to be a JSON type, it should be possible to use a raw query to directly query the JSON column in particular.

If you're curious about said aspect, here's a sample of what it could look like in SQL Server 2016:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO Test (JsonData) VALUES ('["Test"]'), ('["Something"]')
SELECT * FROM Test CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonData, '$') WITH (Value VARCHAR(100) '$') AS n WHERE n.Value = 'Test'
DROP TABLE Test
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something like this via [CompiledExpression](https://github.com/damieng/Linq.Translations/blob/master/Microsoft.Linq.Translations/CompiledExpression.cs).

```
using Microsoft.Linq.Translations;

// (...) namespace, class, etc

private static readonly CompiledExpression<MyClass, List<string>> _myExpression = DefaultTranslationOf<MyClass>
    .Property(x => x.MyProperty)
    .Is(x => new List<string>());

[NotMapped]
public List<string> MyProperty
{
    get { return _myExpression.Evaluate(this); }
}
```

I hope there are better / prettier solutions though ;)