# Colon ':' error - Not all named parameters have been set in Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I got a problem whenever I pass char ":" from the user interface.  NHibernate mistakes it as a named parameter and throws an error, since there isn't any value for it.

Exception is :-

> Not all named parameters have been
>   set: [%] [SELECT COUNT (*)  FROM Table
>   t WHERE t.FirstName LIKE ':%' AND
>   t.ID IN (38, 20)]"

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably creating the query in a wrong way (concatenating strings, maybe?)

All of these work:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Test2>()
       .Add(Restrictions.Like("FirstName", ":%"))
       .UniqueResult<Test2>();

session.CreateQuery("from Test2 where FirstName like :expr")
       .SetParameter("expr", ":%")
       .UniqueResult<Test2>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters when using SQL LIKE. Try passing the parameter as `@"\" + ":";`.

Comment: Please show the code that calls the query. See also the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492984/how-do-i-escape-a-like-clause-using-nhibernate-criteria

Comment: This is the inner exception after escaping special char....
{"Not all named parameters have been set: [%] [SELECT COUNT (*)  FROM Table t WHERE t.FirstName LIKE '\\:%']"}

Comment: I was looking for the HQL or Criteria code that is generating the SQL. What database is this? Anyway, it appears I've been leading you astray, this is an NHibernate, not a database, exception. I got a number of hits on it from Google but it's unclear if it's ever been addressed. The workaround is to use named parameters. Here's an example for Castle: http://www.castleproject.org/ActiveRecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/hql.html.