# How to query for data containing square brackets when using NHibernate.Linq Query<T>

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nhibernate

Some records in my database contain square brackets, eg.

```
dafalgan [1gram]
valium [15mg]
...
```

However when I want to query this with NHibernate.Linq using the following expression

```
return x => x.Description.Contains(searchTerm)
```

where searchTerm is 'dafalgan [1gram]'
the following SQL is used/generated:

```
SELECT        FieldName1, FieldName2
FROM            TableName
WHERE        (Description LIKE '%' + N'dafalgan [1gram]' + '%')
```

This doesn't return any results because SQL Server considers `[` to be the start of a regular expression match for any one of the characters between brackets.  This is only an issue with SQL Server, pl-sql does not consider `[` to be a special character.

[NH-938](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-938) mentions an overload for `Restrictions.Like` allowing to pass an escape character but I have no control over the code used (part of NHibernate.Linq).

I know I can do a `searchTerm.Replace("[", "[[]");` in my code but I was looking for a more general solution, eg. adding it to Hibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect because it's specific only to SQL Server.

Comment: See this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492984/how-do-i-escape-a-like-clause-using-nhibernate-criteria) and comments for how to escape the expression in the Criteria API. I don't know how to do it in LINQ, good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Jamie Ide 's link, the following works for me:

```
    private static AbstractCriterion MatchModeAnywhereSafeCriterion(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        const char escapeChar = '\u001B';
        var safeValue = value.Replace("%", escapeChar + "%").Replace("_", escapeChar + "_")
            .Replace("[", escapeChar + "[");
        return Restrictions.Like(propertyName, safeValue, MatchMode.Anywhere, escapeChar);
    }
```