# How to make linq generate sql statement that concatenates column values on the sql server

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I know there is a way to concatenate the values of a column using sql statement as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string). For example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ', '+ Name AS 'data()' from Names for xml path(''))
       ,3, 255) as "MyList"
```

Is it possible to make **linq to sql** generate the concatenation in the database as a subquery not in the memory or with many additional queries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Linq to concatenate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217805/using-linq-to-concatenate-strings)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/how-to-join-int-to-a-character-separated-string-in-net

Comment: a: there are simpler ways to concatenate - a `declare @s varchar(max) = '' select @s = @s+','+Name from Names select @s` is much simpler, and b: does `db.ExecuteQuery<string>` count as an option?

Comment: Thansks @MitchWheat for the comments, but both of your suggestions make the concatenation in the memory. I want to make it on the SQL Server instead as this is part of a very heavy query and if I use Join() it make lots of separate queries.

Comment: @MarcGravell I asked how to make the LINQ TO SQL generate the query. I know that this is a easier way but if I am writing the query in T-SQL

Comment: To generate the query: not that I know of

Comment: Is their a particular reason to why you need it to be done in the DB rather than in code?

Comment: cos in the code it makes more than 100 queries