# Convert a list into a comma-separated string

Tags: c#, .net

My code is as below:

```
public void ReadListItem()
{
     List<uint> lst = new List<uint>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
     string str = string.Empty;
     foreach (var item in lst)
         str = str + item + ",";

     str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
     Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Output: `1,2,3,4,5`

What is the most simple way to convert the `List<uint>` into a comma-separated string?

Comment: `String.Join` is all you need.

Comment: `var csvString = String.Join(",", lst);` should do it.

Comment: For anyone who wants to reopen this, if it's not too localized it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring

Comment: Similar (from 2008): *[How can I join int\[\] to a character-separated string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856)*

Answer (score 428, accepted):

Enjoy!

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", new List<uint> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));
```

First Parameter: `","`
Second Parameter: `new List<uint> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })`

[String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) will take a list as a the second parameter and join all of the elements using the string passed as the first parameter into one single string.

Comment: In .NET 3.5 and below you have to explicitly convert your list to array with `lst.ToArray()`, as there is no direct overload there yet.

Answer (score 85):

You can use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) method to combine items:

```
var str = String.Join(",", lst);
```

Comment: this does not work for me.  It produces the name of the collection rather than the objects in the list.

Comment: You need to select the property of a class. e.g. `String.Join(",", lst.Select( x => x.Id ));`

Answer (score 33):

Using `String.Join`:

```
string.Join<string>(",", lst);
```

Using LINQ aggregation:

```
lst .Aggregate((a, x) => a + "," + x);
```

Comment: I have list of type int32. when I use aggregate function you mentioned, it says "Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<int,int,int>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type "  and  "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: @Hari You must convert it to string values before you Aggragate to string. So you can do something like this:  list.Select(x => string.Format("{0}:{1}", x.Key, x.Value)).Aggregate((a, x) => a+ ", " + x);

Answer (score 11):

If you have a collection of ints:

```
List<int> customerIds= new List<int>() { 1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
```

You can use `string.Join` to get a string:

```
var result = String.Join(",", customerIds);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is essentially identical to [the accepted answer from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959824/convert-list-into-comma-separated-string/14959865#14959865).

Answer (score 10):

Follow this:

```
List<string> name = new List<string>();

name.Add("Latif");
name.Add("Ram");
name.Add("Adam");
string nameOfString = (string.Join(",", name.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to the below example for getting a comma-separated string array from a list.

Example:

```
List<string> testList= new List<string>();
testList.Add("Apple"); // Add string 1
testList.Add("Banana"); // 2
testList.Add("Mango"); // 3
testList.Add("Blue Berry"); // 4
testList.Add("Water Melon"); // 5

string JoinDataString = string.Join(",", testList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

> You can use String.Join for this if you are using .NET framework> 4.0.

```
var result= String.Join(",", yourList);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@{ var result = string.Join(",", @user.UserRoles.Select(x => x.Role.RoleName));
    @result
}
```

I used in MVC Razor View to evaluate and print all roles separated by commas.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine((string.Join(",", lst.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray())));
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

We can try like this to separate list entries by a comma:

```
string stations = 
haul.Routes != null && haul.Routes.Count > 0 ?String.Join(",",haul.Routes.Select(y => 
y.RouteCode).ToList()) : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<string> listStrings = new List<string>() {"C#", "ASP.NET", "SQL Server", "PHP", "Angular"};
    string CommaSeparateString = GenerateCommaSeparateStringFromList(listStrings);
    Console.Write(CommaSeparateString);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string GenerateCommaSeparateStringFromList(List<string> listStrings){return String.Join(",", listStrings);}
```

*[Convert a list of string to a comma-separated string in C#](http://www.codesolution.org/convert-a-list-of-string-to-comma-separated-string-c/)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also override ToString() if your list items have more than one string:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }

    public string string2 { get; set; }

    public string string3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(
        ","
        , string1
        , string2
        , string3);
    }
}
```

To get a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) string:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.string1 = "string1";
item.string2 = "string2";
item.string3 = "string3";

List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
list.Add(item);

string strinCSV = (string.Join("\n", list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categories = ['sprots', 'news'];
categoriesList = ", ".join(categories)
print(categoriesList)
```

This is the output:
sprots, news

Comment: From what C# version is this valid?

Comment: Is this Javascript? (the question is about C#)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate list entities by a comma like this:

```
//phones is a list of PhoneModel
var phoneNumbers = phones.Select(m => m.PhoneNumber)    
                    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                        (current, next) => current.Append(next).Append(" , ")).ToString();

// Remove the trailing comma and space
if (phoneNumbers.Length > 1)
    phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers.Remove(phoneNumbers.Length - 2, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of *google-collections.jar* which has a utility class called Joiner:

```
String commaSepString = Joiner.on(",").join(lst);
```

Or you can use the StringUtils class which has a function called *join*. To make use of StringUtils class, you need to use common-lang3.jar

```
String commaSepString=StringUtils.join(lst, ',');
```

For reference, refer this link *[Convert Collection into Comma Separated String](http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2015/08/convert-collection-into-comma-separated.html)*

Comment: The question was about C#, not Java.